# express redirect headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express:

```
// check user session
var user = req.user;
if(!user)
    res.redirect('/login');

res.render('report/search');
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

How to stop after redirect?

Comment: add a `return` before res.redirect?

Comment: .. or use `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In expressjs any method on `responose` liek `redirect`, `render`, `json`, etc doesn't stop the execution of the request handler and it executes until the end. You can have any code there and it will work, but you can't send the response to the client twice, that's why you're getting this error.

To solve it you need to either use `return` `if-else` clause:

```
var user = req.user;
if(!user)
    return res.redirect('/login');

return res.render('report/search'); //this return is not required, but it's still good to have it there
```

Or:

```
var user = req.user;
if(!user) {
    res.redirect('/login');
}
else {
    res.render('report/search');
}
```